# How to edit the stock values in WooCommerce in a php hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a website in WordPress and I'm using WooCommerce as well as Advanced Ads to display Products on my Website. I want to sell single digital products so they will always have either 1 or 0 as there stock values. The customer will pay a price to buy the product for a set amount of time. Right now if someone buys the product the stock value gets lowered to 0 as expected but as soon as the bought time expires, the product becomes available again but the stock does not increase to 1 again. Advanced Ad sends me a notification that the time has expired, now I want to use a php hook to this function and increase the stock value to 1 again as soon as the time is expired.

The biggest issue for me is finding the specific function in WooCommerce to hook onto. I already have a functions.php in my child-theme to merge these two functions but I can't really find them in the plugin directory and I don't really know what to search for on the internet, the documentation or in my editor. Does someone have experience with these two plugins and can tell me where I can find these two functions or a good workflow to find such functions in general?

Right now my hook looks like this:

```php
add_action( 'advanced-ads-ad-expired', 'increase_stock_when_ad_expires', 10, 2 );

function increase_stock_when_ad_expires( $ad_id, $ad ) {
    $ad_id = absint( $ad_id );
    
    if ( ! $ad_id ) {
        return;
    }
    
    wc_increase_stock_levels( $product_id );
}
```

Thats all I could come up with at the moment. I don't know if my hook is correct or if I'm even using the correct functions to hook on. I'm not much of a backend programmer as you might can tell. Usually I can fiddle my way around these kind of things but this time I'm a little lost.